# Bias of single blind journal

Tags: publications

I have submitted my manuscript to a single blind high quality journal. My idea is novel and based on an idea published in their journal. After two weeks, it got desk rejected because the data seems not interested (there is no restriction on the used data by the journal)! I have sent it to another journal and got rejected with many mistakes by the reviewers. Then, I have submitted it to double-blind journal, it got interesting comments, as the idea is excellent but not within the scope of the journal and ask me to follow their comments and submit it to another more relative journal. My paper is accepted now and got published. My question is: is single-blind bais? Do the reviewers judge the paper based on the author index or region?

Comment: What you have gone through seems normal, and that you have misjudged the quality or scope of your work with respect to a journal.   Submitting to a journal takes experience.  You need to tick all the 'boxes'; i.e., your article must look like it belongs.   It is like sending a half cooked meal to a customer, and asking the customer for comments.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer to your question is that there is no way to know whether or to what extent bias was a factor in the rejections.

There is literature on the bias problem, using data on many submissions to many journals, but it would be hard to claim (and document) any single instance.

I'm glad your paper found a home.

Answer (score 2):

No one can speak for all reviewers, but, at a reputable journal, that shouldn't happen. Single blind reviewing is to prevent pressure put on reviewers by authors, especially those with powerful constituencies.

You don't speak about the "quality" of the various journals, other than the first. There may have been different reasons for rejection. The first, for out of scope has nothing to do with the authors.

The bigger danger in single blind reviewing is when the author is a "friend" of the author. That should be revealed to the editor (by the reviewer) and they should probably decline the review.

Certainly, the system isn't perfect, but mostly it works as intended.